# Laravel not getting Accessor Trying to get property on a non-object

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to get the value of a map object to check if a user made a rating or not.

> `{{ $book->rated }}` is returning neither false or true.

in tinker

> $book->getTypeAttribute(); PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of
>   non-object in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/elirating/app/Book.php on line
>   40

This method needs to get the type of the rating, the default value is set to false

```
public function getTypeAttribute(){        
    return Rate::where('type', $this->attributes['id'])->where('user_id',auth()->user()->id) === self::RATED; 
}
```

**Book.php**

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use willvincent\Rateable\Rateable;
use App\User;
use App\Rate;

class Book extends Model
{

    use Rateable;

    const RATED = "true";
    const NOT_RATED = "false";

    protected $fillable = [ 'user_id', 'title', 'description'];


    public function scopeGetBook($query, $book_name )
    {
        return $query->where('slug',  $book_name );
    }

    public function setTitleAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['title'] = $value;
        $this->attributes['slug'] = str_slug($value);

    }

    public function scopeGetBookUser($query, $user_id)
    {
        return $query->where('user_id',  $user_id )->first();
    }

    public function getTypeAttribute(){        
        return Rate::where('type', $this->attributes['id'])->where('user_id',Auth()->user()->id) === self::RATED; 
    }
```

**Rate.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;


use App\User;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use willvincent\Rateable\Rateable;

class Rate extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'type',
        'rating'
    ];


    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $table = 'ratings';





}
```

**BookController.php** (this is how the type is being set, and how im trying to retrieve the value)

```
public function rate(Request $request, $book_id)
{

    $book = Book::find($book_id);
    $rating = $book->ratings()->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->first();

    if(is_null($rating)){
        $ratings = new Rating();
        $ratings->rating =  $request['rating'];
        $ratings->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
        $ratings->type = Book::RATED;
        $book->ratings()->save($ratings);




        return json_encode($book);

    }
    else{
       return response()->json(['status' => 'You already left a review']);
    }
}

  public function show($book_name)
{
    $books = Book::with('ratings')->GetBook($book_name)->get();


    $data = $books->map(function(Book $book){

        $book['rated'] = $book->getTypeAttribute();

        return $book;

    });

    return view('books.show', compact('data', $data));
}
```

**HTML**

```
  <div id="rateYo" data-rateyo-rating="{{  $book->userSumRating or 0}}" data-rateyo-read-only="{{ $book->rated }}" > ></div>
```

image(the read-only attribute needs to have either true of false) it doesn't show neither.

[image]

Comment: There could be a couple of places that this is failing, but my guess would be in `auth()->user()->id` either `auth()` or `user()` is returning a non object (string, array etc). You could split out the results of these calls into variables on separate lines and see if the line number error changes.

Comment: ok im going to remove the auth and see what happens

Comment: i get `null` in tinker, but a user already made a rating, the type needs to return `true` and not null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `first` or `get` on the query in the accessor:

```
return Rate::where(['type' => $this->getKey(), 'user_id' => auth()->id()])->first()
```

Also, when using accessors, you don't call the full function, as in `getTypeAttribute`, you only use the attribute name, `type`.

```
// wrong
$book['rated'] = $book->getTypeAttribute();

// right
$book['rated'] = $book->type;
```

However, I think what you should be doing to find if a user has left a rating is to use the `exists` or `doesntExist` query functions. For example:

```
// this will return true/false
public function getRatedAttribute()
{
    return Rate::where(['type' => $this->getKey(), 'user_id' => auth()->id()])->exists();
}
```

Append the attribute to the `Book` model:

```
// this will add the attribute to each book in the query result.
protected $appends = ['rated']; // or type
```

Then you can simply use:

```
$book->rated; // true if a rating exists, otherwise false.
```

Comment: let me give this a go

Comment: whats wrong with `$book->getTypeAttribute();` approach

Comment: The `get` and `Attribute` portion of the function are there for Laravel to identify it as an accessor. The point of defining accessors is so you can create psuedo attributes and use them as you would real ones.

Comment: `$book['rated'] = $book->type;` didn't work, it doesn't give me a true or false within `data-rateyo-read-only="{{ $book->rated }}"`

Comment: I just updated my answer, I think using `exists` will be what you need.

Comment: yeah its  still null,  i added a column name on the ratings table called type and the default value is false. just to let you know

Comment: should  `getRatedAttribute()`  be  `getTypeAttribute()`

Comment: Just so I'm clear, you're trying to append a true/false property to each book, indicating if the user has left a rating for each one?

Comment: Correct digital and `getRatedAttribute` function works in tinker, when i pass this over to the book controller it shows up null

Comment: Ok, I added more to the answer. Try using the `$appends` property within the `Book` model.

Comment: let me try this out

Comment: it didn't work, ill post a picture of whats going on.

Comment: yeah its still not working, i re-read your code several times.

Comment: Hmm, last thing I can think of here, try doing `data-rateyo-read-only="{{ $book->rated ? 'true' : 'false' }}"`.

Comment: it works, thanks how did you know all this, and how did you learn all of this, do you just have experience with this

Comment: I've been using Laravel for a few years now, learned most of it from reading the documentation and working on open source projects. Glad to hear you got it working.